# understanding javascript typeof date behaviour

Tags: javascript

Here's the code :

```
var d = new Date();

console.log(typeof(d+1)); //string

console.log(typeof(d-1)); // number
```

why does it produce different results?

Comment: Well, `"3" + 1` is a string, while `"3" - 1` is a number, it's because the plus sign is also used for concatenation in javascript, and the Date object is converted to a string in the first one, and a number in the second one. And... this is a duplicate.

Comment: [Welcome to the world of weakly typed programming language](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(date + 1)` returns a string, because of string concatenation

`(date - 1)` returns a number because of type conversion

Basically, a string plus a number returns a string with a number appended to the end. This is because the `+` operator is used to concatenate strings.

On the other hand, when you subtract a number from a string, JavaScript performs automatic type conversion.

Form more information, look here

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp